# Create pandas DatetimeIndex without leap day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to create a pandas DatetimeIndex that contains a range of dates around the leap day for various years. Some years are a leap year and some are not. The caveat here though is that I want all of these lists of dates to be the same length. Let's look at some examples.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

leap=pd.date_range('2020-02-27-12',pd.to_datetime('2020-02-27-12')+dt.timedelta(days=2),freq='6H')

DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-27 12:00:00', '2020-02-27 18:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 00:00:00', '2020-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 12:00:00', '2020-02-28 18:00:00',
               '2020-02-29 00:00:00', '2020-02-29 06:00:00',
               '2020-02-29 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6H')
len(leap)
9
```

One of the most common approaches to avoiding leap days in this format is to simply remove them from the list.

```
leap=leap[(leap.day != 29) | (leap.month != 2)]
len(leap)
6
```

This works fine if I just want to remove the leap day and don't care about the specific length of the list.

Let's do the same exercise for a non-leap year.

```
leap=pd.date_range('2021-02-27-12',pd.to_datetime('2021-02-27-12')+dt.timedelta(days=2),freq='6H')

DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-27 12:00:00', '2021-02-27 18:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 00:00:00', '2021-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 12:00:00', '2021-02-28 18:00:00',
               '2021-03-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 06:00:00',
               '2021-03-01 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6H')

len(leap)
9
```

Naturally, the first two have the same length. However, when we remove the leap dates from the first list we can now see that the lengths are different, as 6 =/ 9.

This leads to the ultimate question: how can I create a pandas date range that would take the first list and skip over the leap days and go straight to March, keeping the length of the list at 9?

---

For context, I am indexing geospatial (3D) data using a centered date approach. For example, if I want to look at data at some point on the globe on Jan 5, I analyze the data 2 days before and after Jan 5 (Jan 3-7). In doing this approach over a long period of time (>30 years) I get a better climatological sense of the variable I am analyzing. To do this indexing I am looping over dates and using the pandas date range approach described above. This is the loop I am using to approach a problem in indexing geospatial (3D) data:

```
times=pd.date_range('1979-09-01','1980-04-30-18', freq='6H')
final_times = times[(times.day != 29) | (times.month != 2)]
years=np.arange(1979,2020,1)
for i in final_times:
    print(i)

    times_list=[]

    for j in years:
        times_forward=pd.date_range(i.replace(year=j),i.replace(year=j)+dt.timedelta(days=2), freq='6H')
        times_back=pd.date_range(i.replace(year=j)-dt.timedelta(days=2),i.replace(year=j)-dt.timedelta(hours=6), freq='6H')
        total_times=times_forward.union(times_back)
        times_list.append(total_times)
    combined_times=pd.DatetimeIndex([item for sublist in times_list for item in sublist]).sort_values()
```

When running this code as is the date lists that surround the leap day are shorter in length than those that are not near the leap day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use `DateOffset` objects, the problem is sort of handled for you:

```
>>> pd.date_range('2021-02-27-12', periods=9, freq='6H')
DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-27 12:00:00', '2021-02-27 18:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 00:00:00', '2021-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 12:00:00', '2021-02-28 18:00:00',
               '2021-03-01 00:00:00', '2021-03-01 06:00:00',
               '2021-03-01 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6H')
>>> pd.date_range('2021-02-27-12', periods=9, freq='6H') - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-27 12:00:00', '2020-02-27 18:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 00:00:00', '2020-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 12:00:00', '2020-02-28 18:00:00',
               '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-03-01 06:00:00',
               '2020-03-01 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This does what you want, as long as you reference year is not a leap year. Note that if you’re basing yourself off a leap year you’ll have twice the same date, i.e. you’ll compare both the 28th and 29th to the 28th of the previous or next year:

```
>>> pd.date_range('2020-02-27-12', periods=9, freq='6H')
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-27 12:00:00', '2020-02-27 18:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 00:00:00', '2020-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 12:00:00', '2020-02-28 18:00:00',
               '2020-02-29 00:00:00', '2020-02-29 06:00:00',
               '2020-02-29 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6H')
>>> pd.date_range('2020-02-27-12', periods=9, freq='6H') + pd.DateOffset(years=1)
DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-27 12:00:00', '2021-02-27 18:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 00:00:00', '2021-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 12:00:00', '2021-02-28 18:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 00:00:00', '2021-02-28 06:00:00',
               '2021-02-28 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I’m not sure if this is problematic − the index then contains duplicated items but that’s about the only drawback I suppose.

Based on this, here’s a function that gives, for a given date, the index of each year’s dates (in the range) to compare:

```
def compare_times(datetime, periods=9, freq='6H', years=np.arange(1979, 2021)):
    ref_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([
        *pd.date_range(datetime, periods=1 + periods // 2, freq=f'-{freq}')[::-1],
        *pd.date_range(datetime, periods=1 + periods // 2, freq=freq)[1:]
    ])
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(np.concatenate([ref_index + pd.DateOffset(years=y -datetime.year) for y in years]))
```

There is now no issue anymore, as long as you don’t call the function with a 29th of February. And if you do, non-leap years will return the same number of items but with duplicate entries for the 28th of February:

```
>>> compare_times(pd.Timestamp(2020, 2, 29))
DatetimeIndex(['1979-02-28 00:00:00', '1979-02-28 06:00:00',
               '1979-02-28 12:00:00', '1979-02-28 18:00:00',
               '1979-02-28 00:00:00', '1979-02-28 06:00:00',
               '1979-02-28 12:00:00', '1979-02-28 18:00:00',
               '1979-03-01 00:00:00', '1980-02-28 00:00:00',
               ...
               '2019-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-28 00:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 06:00:00', '2020-02-28 12:00:00',
               '2020-02-28 18:00:00', '2020-02-29 00:00:00',
               '2020-02-29 06:00:00', '2020-02-29 12:00:00',
               '2020-02-29 18:00:00', '2020-03-01 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=378, freq=None)
```

Here you can see the duplicates in 1979.

Comment: This does what I was looking for, thanks.